# Can a model be created on Spark batch and use it in Spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming

Can I create a model in spark batch and use it on Spark streaming for real-time processing?

I have seen the various examples on Apache Spark site where both training and prediction are built on the same type of processing (linear regression).

Comment: As I understand it, Spark streaming isn't real streaming. It breaks the streams into batches, which would allow the batch model you've trained to work nicely. If you want _real_ stream-processing for real-time data, you might look at Kafka, Flink, or Storm.

Comment: @erip I'm not sure OP means "real-time" as in sub-second streaming.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov What other meaning could it have? Real-time batches of training data?

Comment: @erip You never know what one means when they say "real-time". Could be that 2-3 seconds processing time is sufficient for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one more solution which I just implemented.

I created a model in spark-Batch.
suppose the final model object name is  regmodel.

```
final LinearRegressionModel regmodel =algorithm.run(JavaRDD.toRDD(parsedData));
```

and spark context name is sc as

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

Now in a same code I am creating a spark streaming using the same sc

```
final JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc,new Duration(Integer.parseInt(conf.getWindow().trim())));
```

and doing prediction like this:

```
JavaPairDStream<Double, Double> predictvalue = dist1.mapToPair(new PairFunction<LabeledPoint, Double,Double>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public Tuple2<Double, Double> call(LabeledPoint v1) throws Exception {
                    Double p = v1.label();
                    Double q = regmodel.predict(v1.features());
                    return new Tuple2<Double, Double>(p,q);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

> Can I create a model in spark batch and use it on Spark streaming for real-time processing?

Ofcourse, yes. In spark community they call it offline training online predictions. Many training algorithms in spark allow you to save the model on file system HDFS/S3. Same model can be loaded by a streaming application. You simply call predict method of the model to do predictions.

See the section Streaming + MLLib in [this link](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/30/diving-into-spark-streamings-execution-model.html).

For example, if you want to train a DecisionTree offline and do predictions online...

In batch application -

```
    val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
    model.save(sc, "target/tmp/myDecisionTreeClassificationModel")
```

In streaming application -

```
    val sameModel = DecisionTreeModel.load(sc, "target/tmp/myDecisionTreeClassificationModel")
    sameModel.predict(newData)
```

Comment: in batch, sc belongs to sparkcontext and  sc again in streaming belongs to spark batch or its sparkstreamingcontext. I am using Java to develop the application .. here I seen the  Save and load operation are applicable only on Sparkcontext(Scala) however not for JavaSparkContext

Comment: @Saurabh StreamingContext wraps the original SparkContext. Same is true for both java & scala. Look at [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression) example, switch to "Java" tab for Linear Regression save & load example (last 2 lines of each examples). Look at the this javadoc of [JavaStreamingContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaStreamingContext.html#sparkContext()) the sparkContext() method will return JavaSparkContext.